# Android: Get XML from SAX Element

Tags: android, xml, sax

Can I get a string of XML from a SAX Element class in Android? For example, in DOM parsing in .NET, we can get the OuterXml or InnerXml of a node. Unless I'm overlooking something, it seems that there is no way to do that either using SAX or DOM parsing in Android. Am I right about that (I hope not)?

Using SAX, we can do something like:

```
Element childElt = rootElt.getChild(CHILD_ELT_NAME);
if(childElt != null) {
 childElt.setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
  @Override
  public void end(String body) {
   //Do something with the body string
  }
 });
}
```

That will allow us to get at the "value" of the child element. Is there anything similar that will allow us to get at the XML representation of the element and its children?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try out other XML abstractions than DOM; SAX is awfully inconvenient for such tasks... it's simple with DOM, and relatively simpler (than SAX) with bundled pull parser (or Stax) as well?

Comment: DOM Is actually better than SAX, but still cumberson...

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to do operations that are tree structure sensitive, you should use DOM.  What you appear to be trying to do would seem to fit that description, so I would suggest you use a DOM parser.

For a discussion of SAX v. Dom (Event vs. Tree) see: http://www.saxproject.org/event.html

Comment: For a discussion of DOM parsing in Java (Android), see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#CCHEEHHB

Answer (score 0):

With [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sf.net), you can get the token index and convert them to string for further processing, if simplicity is what you look for.